# Why OCMClassMock is not creating a mock object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

I made my problem to simple version. I want to mock NSDictionary.

In my test class I am mocking NSDictionary this way:

```
NSDictionary* mockDict = OCMClassMock([NSDictionary class]);
OCMStub([mockDict objectForKey:@"account_type"]).andReturn(@"Mock ACC1 account_type");
OCMStub([mockDict objectForKey:@"account_number"]).andReturn(@"Mock ACC1 account_number");
```

now I hit the real code this way:

First I create an instance of my VC.

```
CTRegisterPIckAccountViewController *_sutVC;
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]];
_sutVC = (CTRegisterPIckAccountViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AccountListViewController"];
```

Then I call

```
[_sutVC tableView:mockTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:mockIndexNotSelected];
```

In this VC I have used UITableViewDelegate in interface and I call this function:

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSDictionary *account = [_accounts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *Tmp = [account objectForKey:@"account_type"];

}
```

But when I put break point,. Instance of mockDict exist in only test class. And I get Nil. My expectation is

```
[account objectForKey:@"account_type"]
```

This must return the string value I stubbed above but return nil.

Answer (score 0):

In general, creating a mock object doesn't magically swizzle it into use everywhere. You need to use some form of [Dependency Injection](https://qualitycoding.org/dependency-injection/). The most common forms of DI are passing the object as an argument to the initializer, or setting it as a property.

For OCMock, mocking class methods is an exception: It does swizzle all uses of the class method. But not instance methods.